# Is possible to auto-import a module from a different subfolder in other subfolder?

Tags: python, plugins, path

I have a kind of plugin system, with this layout:

- Python

  - SDK

    - Plugins

      - Plugin1
      - Plugin2

All 3 have a `__init__.py` file. I wonder if is possible to be able to do `import SDK` from any plugin (as if `SDK` was in the site-packages folder).

I'm in a situation where need to deploy, update, delete, add or change `SDK` files or any of the plugins under non-admin accounts, and wonder if I can get `SDK` in a clean way (I could `sys.path.append` in all plugins but I wonder if exist a better option).

I imagine that using this in the Plugins init coulkd work:

```
import sys
import os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..'))

print ROOT_DIR
sys.path.append( ROOT_DIR )
```

But clearly is not executed this code (I imagine `__init__.py` was auto-magicalled executed in the load of the module ☹)

Answer (score 2):

- Python

  - `start.py`

    ```
    from SDK.Plugins import Plugin1
    print Plugin1.test()
    ```
  - SDK

    - `__init__.py`
    - Plugins

      - `__init__.py`
      - `Plugin1.py`

        ```
        from SDK.Plugins import Plugin2
        def test():
            return Plugin2.test2()
        ```
      - `Plugin2.py`

        ```
        def test2():
            return "This worked!"
        ```

---

```
# python start.py
This worked!
```

This will work because in `Plugin1.py` you are doing an import *relative to `start.py`*, the executed script, not to itself.

If you were to execute directly `Plugin1.py`, you'd have to mess with the path, but if it's always going to be used from a script higher on the folder hierarchy, then this is the cleanest way to do it.